# Генерация пересекающихся подмножеств

Tags: алгоритм, множества

Был вчера в гостях, где моему малому показали [игру Доббль](http://www.igroved.ru/games/dobble/). В ней имеется набор карточек с резными пиктограммами, го главное - на любых двух карточках всегда имеется одна и только одна общая пиктограмма.

С математической точки зрения это означает - имеется множество из `N` элементов; нужно построить как можно большее количество подмножеств из `M < N` элементов, обладающих тем свойством, что каждые два подмножества имеют один и только один общий элемент.

Как решить эту задачу? Каким алгоритмом сгенерировать эти подмножества? Пусть хоть для каких-то нетривиальных вариантов - для `3` и `2`, как вы понимаете, решение тривиальное :), как и решение с единственным для всех общим элементом.

Буду признателен как за готовое решение, так и за любые идеи.

Comment: _для `N` и `2`, как вы понимаете, решение тривиальное._ Для N>3 я не вижу решения, использующего более 3 элементов из N. Так что тут до тривиальности имхо далековато...

Comment: @Akina Да, это я погорячился... Подправлю :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ответ 1-ый** - не верный, потому как недооценил всей прелести поставленной проблемы

*Я предполагаю, что можно не вдаваться в дебри пересечений множеств, а просто выделив два подмножества, что уже не так сложно, "примешать" к ним одно и тоже значение, которое в них не входит.* (*одна из любых идей*)

**Ответ 2-ой** - к сожалению не мой, неудержался, [подсмотрел](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303497/what-is-the-algorithm-to-generate-the-cards-in-the-game-dobble-known-as-spo) на просторах инета.

```
\#define PRINT(x) printf("%2d  ", (x)+1)

main() {
int i, j, k, r = 0, n = 7;

// first card
printf ("Card %2d:  ", ++r);
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    PRINT (i);
}
printf ("\n");

// n following cards
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    printf ("Card %2d:  ", ++r);
    PRINT (0);
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        PRINT (n+1 + n*j + k);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

// n*n following cards
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf ("Card %2d:  ", ++r);
        PRINT (i+1);
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            PRINT (n+1 + n*k + (i*k+j)%n); // Good for n = prime number
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

А [здесь](http://ideone.com/LR0Nlm) можно посмотреть решение в действии

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете создать непересекающиеся подмножества и добавлять к ним новые элементы? Не могли бы вы пояснить на конкретном примере? не очень понятна ваша идея.

Comment: у вас 100 разных людей, вы выбираете (рандомом,с конца, с начала) из них две группы по 10 (разных) человек. В исходных ста осталось 80. Из 80 рандомите еще одного и "включаете" в обе группы. Теперь в каждой группе по 11 человек и 1 в каждой группе состоит в обоих группах.

Comment: Откуда взялись 2 подмножества, когда их много?

Comment: Маловато получается подмножеств :)

Comment: @Harry обновил, спасибо за вопрос

Answer (score 1):

> имеется множество из N элементов; нужно построить как можно большее количество подмножеств из M < N элементов, обладающих тем свойством, что каждые два подмножества имеют один и только один общий элемент.

Давайте думать. Что имеем? У нас есть N элементов. В каждой группе должно быть M элементов.

Создадим первую группу. Допустим, в неё включены элементы с номерами от 1 до M.

Создадим вторую группу. Она должна иметь с первой только 1 общий элемент. Пусть это будет элемент 1. Тогда вторая группа содержит элемент 1 и элементы от M+1 до 2*M-1.

Создадим третью группу. Она должна иметь с каждой из ранее созданных только по 1 общему элементу. Ну вариант, когда это опять элемент 1, отметём как тривиальный (но не как невозможный!!!). Тогда это будут элементы 2 (пересекаемся с группой 1) и M+1 (пересекаемся с группой 2), а остальные - это элементы с номерами от 2*M до 3*M-3.

Надеюсь, методика понятна? ну а дальше - самостоятельно... пока не выскочите за N, или пока не кончатся варианты.

PS. Чую запах совершенных чисел...

Comment: Идея понятна, но почему-то кажется, что она будет очень далека от оптимального...

Comment: А мне кажется, что методика оптимальна. Дело в том, что она не имеет ветвлений... генерация очередной группы однозначно определяется уже генерированным набором. PS. По тексту я отказываюсь от варианта дублирования общего элемента - несложно проверить, что даже если свернуть на эту ветку, это не изменит максимального общего количества групп, генерируемых из заданного количества элементов, вне зависимости от того, равно ли N максимальному количеству элементов, которые могут быть использованы, или меньше его.

Answer (score 1):

1. Резервируем первый элемент из N.
2. Разбиваем оставшиеся элементы в группы по M-1 элементов.
3. Добавляем в каждую из групп зарезервированный элемент.

Comment: Это решение - N/M, грубо говоря. Маловато, судя по игре :), и тривиально.

Comment: так требует условие

Comment: что-то мне это напоминает

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Это точно "как можно большее количество подмножеств"?

Comment: @Harry а зачем собирать "как можно большее кол-во подмножеств" когда можно генерить два по необходимости и "примешивать :)" туда одно значение? Разве это не ответ на вопрос "Как решить эту задачу?"?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov уж как минимум можно было упомянуть в своем ответе мой ответ (здесь вроде так принято), а то как-то странно и смешно

Comment: @TimurVI, Ваш ответ и так присутствует, и его время тоже.

Comment: @Harry, если быть точным - то (N-1)/(M-1), и это максимум возможного количества подмножеств.

Answer (score 1):

Случайно увидел в голове перед сном такой вариант для случая `N=M(M-1)/2`. Причём число подмножеств `M`, а их размер `M-1`.

Пронумеруем элементы исходного множества числами от `1` до `N`, а генерируемые множества обозначим `A1`, `A2`, ..., `AM`.

Берём элемент `1` и кладём его в множества `A1` и `A2`. Берём элемент `2` и кладём его в множества `A1` и `A3`, затем элемент `3` в `A1` и `A4` и так далее до `A1` и `AM`. Затем как бы возвращаемся к началу и кладём очередной элемент (с номером `M`) в множества `A2` и `A3`, затем (элемент `M+1`) в `A2` и `A4` и т. д. Пример для `N=6` и `M=4`:

```
123
145
426
563
```

Пример для `N=10` и `M=5` (вместо `10` написал `0`):

```
1234
1567
5289
6830
7904
```

Доказательство придумывать, к сожалению, некогда.